H-NMR: Why do certain protons couple despite being further away and vice versa?
I just started learning about $^1\ce{H}$-NMR. Recently, I studied chapter 13 in Organic Chemistry by Clayden, et al. (Ref.1; specifically pp. 295-298) and came across the following graphic:

I am particularly interested in the olefinic protons highlighted in yellow and purple (by me) that are trans to each other. Clearly, the proton highlighted in purple does not interact with the grey proton on adjacent carbon while the one highlighted in yellow does despite being two carbons further away.
How can this observation be explained?

Reference:

Jonathan Clayden, Nick Greeves, and Stuart Warren, In Organic Chemistry: 2nd Edition; Oxford University Press: Oxford, United Kingdom, 2012 (ISBN 10: 0199270295).


Misassignment. Try switching the yellow and purple assignment and check whether coupling pattern and chemical shifts make more sense then.

Which edition??

2nd edition. I also checked the most recent erratum but there are no significant corrections made in chapter 13 (despite me definitely finding one completely unrelated to my question here). So it is still possible there might be a misassignment that was not corrected.
However, the previous subchapter has dealt with long-range coupling so it made sense to me that those concepts would be applied later. I added the page numbers for better context.
